# Python for loop not looping through all the elements? It is only taking the 1st element

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to scrape the data from naukri.com, here I am trying to scrape the location details for each recruiter visible on the page.

The code I am writing is :

```
def sol7(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Rahul\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)
    
    #getting link of recruiters
    recruiters_tag = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='midSec menu']/li[2]/a")
    driver.get(recruiters_tag.get_attribute('href'))
    
    #search and click for data scientist
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='sugInp']").send_keys('Data science')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='qsbFormBtn']").click()
    
    
    highlight_table_tag = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='highlightable']")
    print(len(highlight_table_tag))
    for i in highlight_table_tag:
        try:
            print((i.find_element_by_xpath("//small[@class='ellipsis']")).text)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('-')
```

1st I have extracted all recruiters details in list highlight_table_tag.
highlight_table_tag includes all the elements on the page however the loop only takes the 0th element of my list.
I want to scrape the location in such a way, if the location tag is not there in each element of highlight_table_tag then print '-' instead.

Please help!!!!

Comment: What does `print(len(highlight_table_tag))` show?

Comment: it will show 50, which is the total number of element in my list.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're calling `find_element_by_xpath()` correctly?  I thought that was a method on `driver`, but you're calling it as a method of `i`.

Comment: I was trying to do that way but it is giving me same value for all 50 elements (0th value every time) , how would I go for finding an xpath for each element in the list? 
Suppose I want to find a specific X path for highlight_table_tag[0]

Comment: `highlight_table_tag = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='highlightable']")`

#     print(len(highlight_table_tag)) 

`for i in highlight_table_tag:`

        `try:`
            `print((driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='highlightable']/span/small")).text)`

        `except NoSuchElementException:`

            `print('-')`



using this with driver.find I am getting the same results, only 0th element is looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While xpathing child elements use . in front of the xpath otherwise you will be getting it from root node. Which ends up with 1 element everytime.

```
print((i.find_element_by_xpath(".//small[@class='ellipsis']")).text)
```

Comment: You are God <3. Thanks alot bro :)

Comment: No problem if this answered your question please accept.